# SelectKBest based on (estimated) amount of features

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to implement a hierarchical text classifier with scikit-learn, with one "root" classifier that arranges all input strings in one (or more) of ~50 categories. For each of these categories, I'm gonna train a new classifier, which solves the actual task.

The reason for this two-layer approach is training performance and memory issues (a classifier which is supposed to separate >1k classes does not perform very well...).

This is what my pipeline looks like for each of these "subclassifiers"

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer(strip_accents=None, lowercase=True, analyzer='char_wb', ngram_range=(3,8), max_df=0.1)),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(norm='l2')),
    ('feat', SelectKBest(chi2, k=10000)),
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(SGDClassifier(loss='log', penalty='elasticnet', alpha=0.0001, n_iter=10))),
])
```

Now to my problem: I'm using `SelectKBest` to limit the model size to a reasonable amount, but for the subclassifiers, there is sometimes not enough input data available so I don't even get to the 10k feature limit, which causes

```
(...)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/univariate_selection.py", line 300, in fit
    self._check_params(X, y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/univariate_selection.py", line 405, in _check_params
    % self.k)
ValueError: k should be >=0, <= n_features; got 10000.Use k='all' to return all features.
```

I don't know how many features I will have without applying the `CountVectorizer`, but I have to define the pipeline in advance. My preferred solution would be to skip the `SelectKBest` step, if there are less than `k` features anyway, but I don't know how to implement this behaviour without calling `CountVectorizer` twice (once in advance, once as part of the pipeline).

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the cleanest option would be to subclass SelectKBest and fallback to identity transformation in your implementation, if k exceeds the number of input features, otherwise just call the super implementation.

Comment: Although this would probably work, I'd like to avoid subclassing of libraray functions in order to ease the upgrade process.

Comment: I don't see any other solution except calling CountVectorizer twice, which I would want to avoid. The transformation interface should anyway be stable in sckit-learn. Why do you think upgrading could be a problem?

Comment: You're right, if that's the only alternative, I'd prefer to create a subclass, but maybe there's a third way here...

Answer (score 5):

I followed the advice of [Martin Krämer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29412485/599739) and created a subclass of `SelectKBest` which implements the desired functionality:

```
class SelectAtMostKBest(SelectKBest):

    def _check_params(self, X, y):
        if not (self.k == "all" or 0 <= self.k <= X.shape[1]):
            # set k to "all" (skip feature selection), if less than k features are available
            self.k = "all"
```

I tried to add this snipped to his answer but the request was rejected so there you are...

Comment: Nice. Even cleaner than messing with the actual transformation.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `SelectPercentile`, which is more meaningful if you don't have a fixed number of features.

Comment: Definitely helps for pipelines. I had `kbest__k: [100, 1000, 10000]` but `10000` was `> n_features` which throws an exception. With `SelectPercentile` one does not have that problem.